# Azure Active Directory Client Credential Flow

Tags: azure, jwt, token

I'm using azure Active Directory, Client Credential Flow in my organization's Web API access control.

I have the below applications registered in the AD:
backend-app 
client1
client2

Now, even if I do not give delegated access in Client1 to backend-api, client 1 is able to acquire a token for the resource "backend-app". Is there anyway I can avoid this from happening? I do not want clients that I've not explicitly given delegated access to be able to acquire the token.

This flow works fine in Native apps, where AAD throws an error indicating the client1 doesn't have required permissions for backend-app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Enterprise applications - Application Name - Properties, there's a setting User assignment required? Setting this will only allow explicitly assigned users to access an application.

Taken from the infobox on the Azure Portal:

> If this option is set to yes, then users must first be assigned to this application before being able to access it.

More info on [Assign users and groups to an application in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/methods-for-assigning-users-and-groups)

Comment: Hi rickvdbosch, thanks for the response. There's no users in my case. Its client credential flow, app to app.